# Assign the value (1) to NA in tiff files

Tags: r, raster, tiff

I have two raster files (values ranges from 0 to 1) and I want to find the difference between them. But the problem is there are certain values those are missing. So I want to assign them value 1 (Like NA=1). How can I do this? Any expert can solve this little query. Thanks

My code is this.

```
  library(raster)
  R1 <- raster ("D:/Results/1.tiff")
  R2 <- raster ("D:/Results/2.tiff")

 Se1= R2-R1
 plot(Se1)
```

Comment: What package supplies the `raster` function?

Comment: Mean you are talking about package for calling a raster? Sorry for bad understanding #  neilfws

Comment: I'm asking what library you loaded to use the `raster` function in your code. It is not a function from "base R".

Comment: Actually I am new R user and I don't know about library but  I load  "library (raster)". I am learning #neilfws

Comment: Only the solution is to make data frame of these raster files and then assign the values otherwise its impossible.

Comment: Can you solve this query? #user_3267

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you may do that with "terra" (the replacement of "raster")

```
 library(terra)
 R <- rast(paste0("D:/Results/", 1:2, ".tiff"))
 R <- subst(R, NA, 1)
 Se1 <- diff(R)
```

Answer (score 1):

How large is your raster files and how limited by memory are you? With `raster`, the optimal memory safe approach when interacting with large files is to use the `reclassify` function shown below. Let me know if it works.

```
# Package names
library(raster)

# Read in files
R1 <- raster("D:/Results/1.tiff")
R2 <- raster("D:/Results/1.tiff")

# use the reclassify function to group values to other values. 
# In this case, NA values to 1.Reclassification is done with matrix rcl , 
# in the row order of the reclassify table.
D1 <- reclassify(R1, cbind(NA, 1))
D2 <- reclassify(R2, cbind(NA, 1))

# Find the difference between the two and plot.
Se1 = R2-R1
plot(Se1)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I am getting error when running D1 line **Error in cbinf(NA,1): could not find function "cbinf"**. What does that mean #Sod

Comment: Look more closely at the answer. There is no 'cbinf` in the answer.

Comment: Ohhh sorry #dcarlson

Comment: If my solution works, please remember to select it as answered and upvote for future users. Best of luck!

Comment: Done #Sod it really work for me